# Sublime Text 3: Buscar y reemplazar principio y final de una cadena manteniendo solo una parte

Tags: sublimetext3

Necesito buscar y reemplazar en sublime text 3 esta cadena:

```
$this->l('ID'),
```

por esta:

```
$this->trans('ID', array(), 'Modules.Bonosnove.Admin'),
```

Necesito hacerlo manteniendo la parte 'ID' que en cada vez que sale, cambia. Esa es la parte variable de la frase.
Sé que se puede hacer con Expresiones Regulares pero no la doy sacado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En el mismo archivo que estas, presionas:

> CTRL+shift+F

Y en el lado inferior aparecerán 3 filas:

- La primera fila es para escribir la palabra que quieres reemplazar.
- La segunda fila es para buscar la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo.
- La tercera fila es para poner la palabra con la que la vas a reemplazar.

Por ultimo en lado derecho superior de las 3 filas, aparecera un boton donde dice "find" ahi presionar y encontrara todas las coincidencias con la primera fila, si es correcto lo que quieres reemplazar solo presionas en el boton que se encuentra en la parte inferior que se llama "replace". Listo eso seria todo, saludos!

Comment: No vale, con eso no puede reemplazar principio y final.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo que necesito es la función regex para cambiar el principio y el final sin que toque la variable que pueda ir en medio.